# how can i get variables from string input from an Inputstream in java

Tags: java, java-io

In Java, how can I create variables like `Date`, `Name`, `URO`, `BLD`, etc., and capture their values from this input stream?

I am trying to create variables from an input that I get from a machine via serial port RS-232.

I am receiving via and `inputStream` and am trying to get values from the stream that comes in this format:

> AUG/31/2017 20:42:24 
>   Name: John Doe     Sex:M 
>   Ward: ADMIN        Age:25 
>   CYBOW 10    (00260) 
>   URO  norm    0.1mg/dl
>   GLU       -        neg 
>   BIL       -        neg 
>   KET       -        neg 
>   S.G              1.020 
>   BLD       +    10RBC/ul 
>   pH                 6.0 
>   PRO       -        neg 
>   NIT       -        neg 
>   LEU       -        neg 
>   (SN=11160520) 
>   ID(                ) 
>   OP(00000000)LOT(00000000)~

Comment: What did you already try? Where exactly do you have a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the rough plan to get your things done. Hope it's clear.

- Store all the variables into Set- Date, Name, URO, BLD
- Now start reading file -line by line
- Once you get a line - store it into string(let say 's') use readLine 
  method
- Now use s.startsWith(key). Key is entries of Set.
- Split the string based on the delimiter. 2nd string is the value.
- Store the key and value in hashmap. like

Date, dateValue

Name, John Doe